# Kubernetes Replicate Volume Data

Tags: kubernetes, replication

I would like to replicate volume data among multiple nodes for redundancy.

I saw that the CSI drivers support [snapshots](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volume-snapshots/) but I was looking for something more [rsync](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-rsync-for-local-and-remote-data-transfer-and-synchronization/).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could perhaps deploy `rsync` as a container, if that is what you are looking for?

Comment: @Jonas would you mind posting your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming back to my own question after learning a fair bit about k8s.

The solution I was really looking for is a cloud native distributed block storage - there are a number of implementation but the one that stands out for me is longhorn - https://longhorn.io/

It will basically synchronize virtual volumes that live on multiple nodes. It has lots of many other features such as snapshots and backups.

It is also referred by the Cloud Native Computing Foundation: https://www.cncf.io/?s=longhorn

Other options include using https://www.gluster.org/, https://rook.io/ etc..

Comment: Thanks for coming back to share this - turns out that Longhorn is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Having analysed the comments it looks like one of the options would be to deploy `rsync` as a container.

For example `rsync` deployments one can visit below links:

- [rsync-deploy](https://hub.docker.com/r/steveltn/rsync-deploy/)
- [A simple Docker deployment with just rsync and SSH](https://medium.com/jaequery/a-simple-docker-deployment-with-only-rsync-and-ssh-b283ad5129d1)

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor seems like a good way to do it. I still have to test it though